# how to open a link in new window by clicking on ad?

Tags: javascript

how to open a link in new window by clicking on ad?

this is my ad code :

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-1933305968388659";
/* Try This...:) */
google_ad_slot = "2365466722";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 15;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

what i want is when this ad get a click a extra link should open in new browser window.

**i tried below but it did't work**

```
<a href="http.example.com"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-1933305968388659";
/* Try This...:) */
google_ad_slot = "2365466722";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 15;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script></a>
```

Comment: Have a read here: http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1354740

Comment: What do you mean a "extra link" ?

Comment: extra link mean by that link i will provide it should open separately in new windows it should not cause the ad link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I have known in the past, and what is shown here:
[Opening the (Adsense) ads in a new window](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1354740)

In most cases, Google does not allow Google ads to open in a new window. In cases where it is allowed, it is controlled by the IP address of the user viewing the ad.

> #### Ad implementation policies
>
> ### Opening the ads in a new window
>
> Generally, it is our policy to not allow Google ads to open in a new window. However, in a few markets, including China, we've found that opening ads in a new window better aligns with expected internet behavior and provides a more consistent, intuitive user experience.
>
> Keeping in mind the importance of the user experience, we've enabled Google ads to open in new windows in locations where this is expected browsing behavior. This functionality is determined by the IP of the user, and is not an option you can select your AdSense account.
>
> We also ask that you don't modify the AdSense ad code or alter the result of clicking on an ad on your website, as such behavior violates our program policies.

That being said, it may be possible to create some workaround to Force the ad to open in a new window, but Google won't like it and they will eventually find out and "punish" you for doing it...
They could:

- Reduce the level of quality associated with your page.
- Lower the revenue (rate) for your ads
- Block your ads
- Restrict, suspend or terminate your account.
- Many other bad things that no one has thought of yet.

I think it would be great for Google to allow clicking ads to open in a new page (or tab) and I think most people would be OK with it, or even perfer it.  It could even be made "Optional" by them (Google) showing a small upwards-arrow within, or near the ad that the user could click to open the ad in a new window.

I don't think Google will do this any time soon. They feel the average user expects that when they click an ad (or any link), they can get back to the previous page by clicking the "Back" button, and if the ad is opened in a new window, the back button is not operational and the user will become confused and feel they have had a bad experience.

As long as Google doesn't want you to do it, my advice would be: Don't do it.  After all, it's their ad, and they want to control how it's displayed and interacted with.

Comment: That is just awful. I made a browser game with a banner, but if player clicks a banner, whole game is canceled and a new page opens in the same window. After returning back, player has to start the the last level again, from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot do it in a new window, according to Google Adsense policies.
But they never said anything about a new tab. New tab is okay.
On Youtube all Google Adsense partnership ads open in new tabs.
That way Youtube visitors don't automatically leave the Youtube website when they click an ad.
This does the same job that the visitors don't leave your website if that's what you need.
New tab is okay. New window no. Does the same job for you though. Youtube does it.

Comment: Taking into consideration user-settings, cross-browser issues, and browser-version issues, how do you reliably control whether a new page will open in a new window or a new tab?